# Поворот части текста в ylabel

Tags: matlab

Прошу, подсказать. Проблема следующая. Есть график. К нему есть ylabel. Как сделать, чтобы у части текста направление букв было параллельно оси OY, а друга часть текста была перпендикулярна оси 0Y. Речь идет о Matlab.
Вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**
Видел такую подпись к графику в одном из последних номеров англоязычного журнала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить отдельные рукояти (handles) для частей текста довольно проблематично, если вообще возможно. Так что, можно попробовать создать вторую ось, на месте основной оси, сделав всю ось невидимой, сделав видимой только подпись.

```
close all
x = linspace(0,2*pi);
y = sin(x);
f1 = figure(1);
ax1 = gca; %переменная для основных осей
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position')); %создаём новую вспомогательную ось на том же месте что и основная ось
set(ax2,'Visible','off');%и делаем её невидимой, чтоб не мешала основному графику
h1 = plot(ax1,x,y,'LineWidth',2);%строим график
yl1 = ylabel(ax1,'Correlation');%первая подпись
yl2 = ylabel(ax2,'(a)','Rotation',0);%вторая подпись с поворотом 0 градусов, вместо 90
set(yl2,'Visible','on');%делаем вторую подпись видимой
set(yl2,'Units','Normalized','Position',[-0.1,0.65,0]);%меняем позицию второй подписи
```

Результат показан ниже. С позицией можно поиграть, в зависимости от нужд и вкуса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, я уже не ожидал ответа. Эту задачу я решил по другому. Я редактировал график средствами консоли. В title второй строкой разместил (a), а потом, используя свойства редактора изображения, сдвинул эту строку и повернул, как мне было нужно. Ваш способ изящней. Ещё раз спасибо.
С уважением Станислав.